# Adding extension to otherTelephone Property

Tags: powershell

I'm hit and miss when it comes to writing PowerShell these days. I currently have a CSV with the following headers - Name, UserName, EXT, UserPrincipleName. I need to add the column data for OtherTelephone into each user's AD profile. I have a basic script going but I wanted to see if I was missing anything or if something needed to be corrected. I've added data to non-array attributes but wasnt sure if it was the same.

```
$users = Import-csv -path ".\extensions.csv"
foreach ($ext in $users {
Get-ADUser -Fi * -prop othertelephone -searchbase "MyOU" | select name,@{n="othertelephone";e={$_.othertelephone -join ";"}} | Set-aduser $_.userName -add @{othertelephone = $ext}
```

Thanks. And as always, I appreciate the help.

Comment: You're missing the closing to your `foreach` statement condition blocks: `(...)`, `{...}`. `Set-ADUser` should take the pipeline input, so you wouldn't need `$_.userName`, which should actually be `$ext.userName` as well as `$ext.ext`. You are also filtering for everyone with each iteration and not specifying a specific user so that should be the main concern.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala appreciate the help. Ill take a look and edit the script. There are roughly 80 users so not sure if I would want to specify a single user in this case would I. Or am I misreading the last line of your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since LDAP attribute [otherTelephone](http://www.selfadsi.org/ads-attributes/user-otherTelephone.htm) is a multivalued (string array) property, I would first check to see if perhaps the new extension from the csv is already set for that user.
Then, if it is not, add it to the existing array.

Try

```
$searchBase = "OU=MyOU, ...."
$users = Import-csv -Path ".\extensions.csv"
foreach ($user in $users) {
    # first check, is csv field EXT populated?
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($user.EXT) {
        Write-Warning "Empty extension value for user $($user.Name) in the CSV.."
        continue   # skip this one and proceed with the next
    }
    # try and find the user using its UserPrincipalName
    $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($user.UserPrincipalName)'" -Properties otherTelephone -Searchbase $searchBase
    if ($adUser) {
        # test if the new extension has already been set (otherTelephone is an array)
        if ($adUser.otherTelephone -contains $user.EXT) {
            Write-Host "Extension $($user.EXT) is already set for user $($user.Name).."
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Adding extension $($user.EXT) to user $($user.Name)"
            # add the new extension to whatever is already set
            # using -Add or -Replace usually wants strongly typed object arrays
            # therefore the cast to [string[]]
            [string[]]$extensions = @($user.EXT) + $adUser.otherTelephone
            $adUser | Set-ADUser -Replace @{otherTelephone = $extensions}
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "User $($user.Name) not found.."
    } 
}
```

Please note the property is called `UserPrincipalName`, not as stated in the question `UserPrincipleName`.

Comment: thanks. However, after running this in a test OU, it says that it cannot find any of the users - User $($user.Name) not found for the 3 users in the OU.

Comment: @nosupport2020 please open your csv in notepad and copy the first 3 or or 4 lines. Then edit your question and paste it in there as formatted text. It looks like you may have a csv that is not delimited with _commas_, but some other character. Are you sure those users can be found in the OU mentioned in the searchbase?

Comment: @nosupport2020 And are the UserPrincipalNames in the csv valid?

Comment: Here is my test data. I broke down the script and it looks like the 2nd IF statement may be an issue. When running the first IF statement, it found the missing extension.


Name,EXT,UserPrincipleName,UserName
John Smith,x6969,jsmith@domain.com,jsmith
John Doe,x666,jdoe@domain.com,jdoe
C Smith,csmith3@domain.com,csmith3

Sorry, I dont know how to format the text in here.

Comment: @nosupport2020 It should be `UserPrincipalName`, not `UserPrincipleName`.. I will update my answer, can you correct that in your csv file?

Comment: Corrected and looks like we have a winner. Thats my fault. Should have caught that. Good looking out and thanks for the help.